# Changing category on post doesn't change permalink

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I have a CPT of 'webinars'. I use that to create posts for a category called 'Upcoming Webinars' that lives on the page /Upcoming-Webinar. I use that category for posts until the event expires (using the Post Expirator plug in). When the event expires (one hour after start time) it gets moved to draft and an email is fired off to the author notifying them their event has been moved to 'draft' status and some things they need to do. The major thing they need to do is change the category from 'Upcoming-Webinars' to 'Archived-Webinars'.

Once that is done, the post is now visible on the /Upcoming-Webinars page. All this works as expected.

The issue is this: When the post is moved from /Upcoming-Webinars to /Archived-Webinars, the permalink still has the category /upcoming-webinars. EX:
Upcoming-Webinars (where it starts) url: http://dev.com/Upcoming-Webinars/page-title/
then it expiers and is moved to /Archived-Webinars/ but the link is still http://dev.com/Upcoming-Webinars/page-title/ and not http://dev.com/Archived-Webinars/page-title/

Comment: This is normal. That's why they are called permalinks. You can use the default style of WordPress `http://example.com/?p=33` if this will suit you more. Checkout: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Thanks, I guess I never noticed permalinks don't change when you update the category. In a way, it makes sense so you dont get duplicate content when you change category. However, makes me want to remove category from URL and just go %postname%